# How to make data available to all objects of a class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, field

This is probably very basic but somehow I cannot figure it out.

Say I have a class `A` which embeds 42 `Thing`s, plus some common data:

```
class A {
  Thing things[42];
  int common_data[1024];
}
```

I would like each `thing` to have access to the common data, but I don't want to copy the data in each Thing object, nor pay the price of a pointer to it in each thing. In other word, I would like `Thing` to look like this:

```
class Thing {
  int ident;
  int f() {
    return common_data[ident];
  }
}
```

Of course here `common_data` is unbound. What is the canonical way to make this work?

FWIW I am working with a subset of C++ with no dynamic allocation (no "new", no inheritance, basically it's C with the nice syntax to call methods and declare objects); I am ideally looking for a solution that fits in this subset.

Comment: make it a static member

Comment: @tobi303 ... of class `Thing`? But then I could not access it from `A`, right?

Comment: Pass the `common_data` to `Thing` methods when it's relevant.

Comment: well then I misunderstood the question. With common, you mean common between `A` and `Thing` ?

Comment: @mqtthiqs Also if I gather correctly, it's supposed to be a non-static member of `A`, but common to all `Things`?

Comment: Why can you not pass a pointer? You aren't doing any dynamic allocation if you are just passing a reference of this, or a pointer to common_data. However, if you really have your hands tied, and don't want to pass any type of pointers. You could always copy the elements of common_data, 1 by 1, to Thing. Whenever there is an update to common_data, using a set method, update each Thing.

Comment: @tobi303 yes, common to `A` (which will fill up `common_data`) and all `Thing`s (which will read from it).

Comment: actually I dont understand what you want to do. You already have all things and the common data in a common container. Why would you need a `int f() { return common_data[ident]; }` in `Thing`?

Comment: @StoryTeller static or non-static, member of A or Thing, I don't really care (there will be one instance of A anyway). All I want is for it to be accessible from A and from all Things.

Comment: @tobi303 sorry if my question was not clear. See reply below.

Comment: @Taztingo copying all elements of `common_data` into each `Thing` is precisely what I want to avoid, since I would then have 42 copies of it in memory. I want to avoid passing a pointer (like in @tobi303's answer below) because 1/ I have to explicitly pass the argument to each function in `Thing` that uses it, which is more work for me and 2/ at run-time I will pay the price of copying the pointer 42 times (each time the function in `Thing` is called).

Comment: @mqtthiqs If you make common_data static then you can access it from Things. A::common_data.

Comment: @Taztingo this seems reasonable in my case since there will be only one instance of `A`. Care writing a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your issue by making the common_data attribute of Class A static. Static variables are shared by all members of class A, and will be accessible if you make it public.

```
class A 
{
  private:
    Thing things[42];
  public:
    static int common_data[1024];
}
```

It can be accessed by doing...

```
A::common_data[index];
```

Comment: Thanks again to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly, but maybe this helps:

```
struct A {
  Thing things[42];
  int common_data[1024];
  void foo(int index) {
      things[index].doSomeThingWithCommonData(int* common_data);
  }
};

struct Thing {
  void doSomeThinWithCommonData(int* common_data) {
      /* now you have access to common_data */
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @tobi303. The problem with your solution is that I have to explicitly pass my data as argument each time I need it (the same way you have to explicitly pass data as arguments if you don't have class, e.g. in C). What I was looking for is a way for my function `f` or your function `doSomethingWithCommonData` to not take the data as argument, but have it already in scope, as if it was a field (or even: making it a field somehow, but retaining access from `A`).

Comment: @mqtthiqs there seems to be something wrong with your class design. If you are worried about passing the data then 1) consider that it is passed-by-reference (ie no copies are involved) 2) you could do whatever `Thing` is supposed to do directly in `A::foo` (but then `A` might need access to `Things` private members)

Comment: @tobi303 He stated that he does not want to copy the pointer, in a previous comment. If you pass by reference it will copy the pointer for each instance. I'm really not sure how to do this other than having a static class, or passing by reference, like you suggested.

Comment: I see what you mean by 2), thanks. About 1) if I'm not wrong, there is still a cost of copying the reference itself from the to the stack frame of the callee, and dereferencing this pointer in each of the `Thing` instances, which seems like a waste since we know statically where `common_data` is stored.

Comment: @mqtthiqs Dont be worried about passing a single pointer. I would be surprised if this ever has a measurable impact on runtime

Comment: @tobi303 actually I work on small embedded STM32 MCUs and this is right into a real-time hot loop where every single instruction counts (esp. if they have to be done 42 time like here). That said, thanks to you and @Taztingo I just got my answer: make common_data static and access it in Thing through `A::common_data`. It will do in my case since there will ever be only one instance of A... Would you guys like to make a solution so I can accept it?

Comment: @mqtthiqs you should have provided this information in the question (small embedded system, there is only one instance of A). Given the question as it is, this is the best answer I could give.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasons for avoiding pointers/reference is based on irrational fears. "Copying" a pointer 42 times is *nothing* (read this word carefully) for the machine. Moreover this is definitely **not** the bottleneck of the application.

So the idiomatic way is to simply use dependency injection, which is indeed a slightly more costly action for you (if passing an array can be considered *costly*), but allows for a much more decoupled design.

This is therefore the solution I recommend:

```
struct Thing {
    using data = std::shared_ptr<std::array<int, 1024>>;
    data common_data;
    Thing(data arg)
        : common_data(arg)
        {}
    // ...
};
```

If the system is costrained, then you should benchmark your program. I can tell you already with almost absolutely certainty that the bottleneck won't be the copying of those 42 pointers.